# How to detect end of speech in microsoft-speech tts sdk

Tags: reactjs, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using **microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk** in react for text to speech. I want to run a specific function when the text is finished being spoken. However I am unable to find a way to detect the end of the speech using the sdk. I just need a way to detect when the audio is finishd playing by the sdk so I can run my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK has a `onAudioEnd` event, see [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/synthesis.html#L341).

Also, remember to close the `synthesizer`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564402/microsoft-cognitive-tts-onaudioend-event-not-working) for details.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you so much!